# How do you count cells using regex that do not match the expression?

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, filter, sum

I want to count the number of cells that do not contain the following words.

- denv
- univ
- du

The above list of words change frequently and in Cell B22 it automatically creates some regex for another formula where I sum another column next to it.

Cell B22 =    `.*denv.*|.*univ.*|.*du.*`

Can I use the same Cell B22 reference for counting everything that **DOES NOT** contain those words?

| Name | Metric |
| --- | --- |
| denver | 5 |
| ohio | 5 |
| dual | 9 |
| dual | 1 |
| maryland | 4 |
| universe | 6 |
| maryland | 1 |
| dual | 2 |
| denver | 7 |

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you would share a link to an editable copy of your sheet. Keep in mind that we don't know what you know and can't see what you see; so what seems perfectly clear to you... isn't quite as clear to those of us "out here." From what I can see in your post, you're probably working too hard at even what you are doing for inclusions; and exclusions would likely be simple as well. But I/we would need to see all the pieces to know for sure what to suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(FILTER(A:A, A:A<>""), B22)=FALSE))
```

[image]

or:

```
=SUM(INDEX(N(REGEXMATCH(FILTER(A:A, A:A<>""), B22)=FALSE)))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! How would you handle summing column B (Metric) using the same steps?